# Run WF in queue

Tags: workflow-foundation

Can I run WF activities not parallel, but in queue?
So in one moment of time only one activity can be run?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would this matter?

I've done a few blog posts explaining how activities run with threads and the parallel activity.

[Windows Workflow Foundation (WF4) Activities and Threads](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/06/23/windows-workflow-foundation-wf4-activities-and-threads.aspx)
[The Workflow Parallel Activity and Task Parallelism](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/06/28/the-workflow-parallel-activity-and-task-parallelism.aspx)

Comment: I have deadlock in database when two activities is running in parallel

Comment: Sorry. Maybe i told incorrectle. I'm running workflow from service.         var application = new WorkflowApplication(Workflow);
                SetApplicationProperties(application);
            application.Load(CampaignRequest.WorkflowId);

            return application;'. So I need to run this workflows one by one ( now they are started in parallel)

Comment: Then the real issue is that multiple instances of your service are starting concurrent Workflows.  With WCF You can configure your ServiceBehavior so that it uses ConcurrencyMode.Single which will ensure that only one instance of your service runs at a time.